# Terraform: AWS-RDS - InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot upgrade aurora-postgresql from 12.11 to 13.6

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

We use terraform to manage our AWS RDS PostgreSQL cluster. When trying to upgrade the RDS PostgreSQL from 12.11 to 13.6 it's failing due to `InvalidParameterCombination` error (Please check below for more details). I have tried to remove the existing parameter group from the cluster before initiating the upgradation, but no luck.

Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "enable_replication" {
  name        = "aurora-pg13-cluster-repl"
  family      = "aurora-postgresql13"
  description = "RDS cluster parameter group replication"

  parameter {
    name         = "rds.logical_replication"
    value        = "1"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }

  parameter {
    name         = "max_worker_processes"
    value        = "50"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }

  parameter {
    name         = "max_replication_slots"
    value        = "50"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "enable_pglogical" {
  name   = "aurora-pg13-pglogical"
  family = "aurora-postgresql13"

  parameter {
    name         = "shared_preload_libraries"
    value        = "pglogical,pg_stat_statements"
    apply_method = "pending-reboot"
  }

  parameter {
    name         = "log_connections"
    value        = "1"
    apply_method = "immediate"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

module "psqldb" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws"
  version = "6.2.0"

  name = "psqldb"

  engine         = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version = "13.6"

  vpc_id         = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_core_metadata.outputs.vpc_id
  subnets        = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_core_metadata.outputs.private_subnets
  instance_class = var.rds_cluster_instance_class
  instances = {
    1 = {}
    2 = {}
  }

  allowed_security_groups = [
    data.terraform_remote_state.aws_core_metadata.outputs.eks_worker_security_group_id,
    data.terraform_remote_state.aws_core_metadata.outputs.bastion_security_group_id
  ]

  allowed_cidr_blocks = local.rds_cidrs
  security_group_egress_rules = {
    to_cidrs = {
      cidr_blocks = local.rds_cidrs
      description = "From allowed_cidr_blocks"
      from_port   = "5432"
      to_port     = "5432"
    }
  }
  deletion_protection         = true
  security_group_description  = "Managed by Terraform"
  storage_encrypted           = true
  apply_immediately           = true
  monitoring_interval         = 10
  publicly_accessible         = false
  skip_final_snapshot         = local.rds_skip_final_snapshot
  allow_major_version_upgrade = true

  db_parameter_group_name         = aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical.name
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.enable_replication.name

  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]

  iam_database_authentication_enabled = true

  tags = local.tags

  autoscaling_enabled      = true
  autoscaling_min_capacity = 2
  autoscaling_max_capacity = 3
}
```

Terraform Apply output:

```
  # aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "enable_pglogical" {
      ~ arn         = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:681496624581:pg:aurora-pg12-pglogical" -> (known after apply)
        description = "Managed by Terraform"
      ~ family      = "aurora-postgresql12" -> "aurora-postgresql13" # forces replacement
      ~ id          = "aurora-pg12-pglogical" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name        = "aurora-pg12-pglogical" -> "aurora-pg13-pglogical" # forces replacement
      + name_prefix = (known after apply)
      - tags        = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all    = {} -> (known after apply)

        parameter {
            apply_method = "immediate"
            name         = "log_connections"
            value        = "1"
        }
        parameter {
            apply_method = "pending-reboot"
            name         = "shared_preload_libraries"
            value        = "pglogical,pg_stat_statements"
        }
    }

  # aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.enable_replication must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group" "enable_replication" {
      ~ arn         = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:681496624581:cluster-pg:aurora-pg12-cluster-repl" -> (known after apply)
        description = "RDS cluster parameter group replication"
      ~ family      = "aurora-postgresql12" -> "aurora-postgresql13" # forces replacement
      ~ id          = "aurora-pg12-cluster-repl" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name        = "aurora-pg12-cluster-repl" -> "aurora-pg13-cluster-repl" # forces replacement
      + name_prefix = (known after apply)
      - tags        = {} -> null
      ~ tags_all    = {} -> (known after apply)

        parameter {
            apply_method = "pending-reboot"
            name         = "max_replication_slots"
            value        = "50"
        }
        parameter {
            apply_method = "pending-reboot"
            name         = "max_worker_processes"
            value        = "50"
        }
        parameter {
            apply_method = "pending-reboot"
            name         = "rds.logical_replication"
            value        = "1"
        }
    }

  # module.psqldb.aws_rds_cluster.this[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_rds_cluster" "this" {
        allow_major_version_upgrade         = true
        apply_immediately                   = true
        arn                                 = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:681496624581:cluster:psqldb"
        availability_zones                  = [
            "us-east-1a",
            "us-east-1b",
            "us-east-1d",
        ]
        backtrack_window                    = 0
        backup_retention_period             = 7
        cluster_identifier                  = "psqldb"
        cluster_members                     = [
            "psqldb-1",
            "psqldb-2",
        ]
        cluster_resource_id                 = "cluster-AGN3JQUSROTLPAX6L6NL3FSYKM"
        copy_tags_to_snapshot               = false
      ~ db_cluster_parameter_group_name     = "aurora-pg12-cluster-repl" -> "aurora-pg13-cluster-repl"
        db_subnet_group_name                = "psqldb"
        deletion_protection                 = true
        enable_global_write_forwarding      = false
        enable_http_endpoint                = false
        enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports     = [
            "postgresql",
        ]
        endpoint                            = "psqldb.cluster-cmt6phsh6krf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        engine                              = "aurora-postgresql"
        engine_mode                         = "provisioned"
      ~ engine_version                      = "12.11" -> "13.6"
        engine_version_actual               = "12.11"
        final_snapshot_identifier           = "final-psqldb-7bf0383d"
        hosted_zone_id                      = "Z2R2ITUGPM61AM"
        iam_database_authentication_enabled = true
        iam_roles                           = []
        id                                  = "psqldb"
        kms_key_id                          = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:681496624581:key/f581b6ba-0295-408c-a3cf-ae1a916f5b9e"
        master_password                     = (sensitive value)
        master_username                     = "root"
        port                                = 5432
        preferred_backup_window             = "02:00-03:00"
        preferred_maintenance_window        = "sun:05:00-sun:06:00"
        reader_endpoint                     = "psqldb.cluster-ro-cmt6phsh6krf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        skip_final_snapshot                 = true
        storage_encrypted                   = true
        tags                                = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        tags_all                            = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        vpc_security_group_ids              = [
            "sg-054df949da5864e56",
        ]

        timeouts {}
    }

  # module.psqldb.aws_rds_cluster_instance.this["1"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "this" {
        apply_immediately                     = true
        arn                                   = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:681496624581:db:psqldb-1"
        auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
        availability_zone                     = "us-east-1b"
        ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019"
        cluster_identifier                    = "psqldb"
        copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
      ~ db_parameter_group_name               = "aurora-pg12-pglogical" -> "aurora-pg13-pglogical"
        db_subnet_group_name                  = "psqldb"
        dbi_resource_id                       = "db-U5CPJMUW6VRXIVHFLHISWWM4VQ"
        endpoint                              = "psqldb-1.cmt6phsh6krf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        engine                                = "aurora-postgresql"
      ~ engine_version                        = "12.11" -> "13.6"
        engine_version_actual                 = "12.11"
        id                                    = "psqldb-1"
        identifier                            = "psqldb-1"
        instance_class                        = "db.t3.medium"
        kms_key_id                            = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:681496624581:key/f581b6ba-0295-408c-a3cf-ae1a916f5b9e"
        monitoring_interval                   = 10
        monitoring_role_arn                   = "arn:aws:iam::681496624581:role/rds-enhanced-monitoring-psqldb"
        performance_insights_enabled          = false
        performance_insights_retention_period = 0
        port                                  = 5432
        preferred_backup_window               = "02:00-03:00"
        preferred_maintenance_window          = "sun:05:00-sun:06:00"
        promotion_tier                        = 0
        publicly_accessible                   = false
        storage_encrypted                     = true
        tags                                  = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        tags_all                              = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        writer                                = true

        timeouts {}
    }

  # module.psqldb.aws_rds_cluster_instance.this["2"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "this" {
        apply_immediately                     = true
        arn                                   = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:681496624581:db:psqldb-2"
        auto_minor_version_upgrade            = true
        availability_zone                     = "us-east-1b"
        ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019"
        cluster_identifier                    = "psqldb"
        copy_tags_to_snapshot                 = false
      ~ db_parameter_group_name               = "aurora-pg12-pglogical" -> "aurora-pg13-pglogical"
        db_subnet_group_name                  = "psqldb"
        dbi_resource_id                       = "db-5X7GWHG67Q6YPPVTGE76LXMV54"
        endpoint                              = "psqldb-2.cmt6phsh6krf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        engine                                = "aurora-postgresql"
      ~ engine_version                        = "12.11" -> "13.6"
        engine_version_actual                 = "12.11"
        id                                    = "psqldb-2"
        identifier                            = "psqldb-2"
        instance_class                        = "db.t3.medium"
        kms_key_id                            = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:681496624581:key/f581b6ba-0295-408c-a3cf-ae1a916f5b9e"
        monitoring_interval                   = 10
        monitoring_role_arn                   = "arn:aws:iam::681496624581:role/rds-enhanced-monitoring-psqldb"
        performance_insights_enabled          = false
        performance_insights_retention_period = 0
        port                                  = 5432
        preferred_backup_window               = "02:00-03:00"
        preferred_maintenance_window          = "sun:05:00-sun:06:00"
        promotion_tier                        = 0
        publicly_accessible                   = false
        storage_encrypted                     = true
        tags                                  = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        tags_all                              = {
            "Account"            = "dev"
            "ApplicationName"    = "psql-base"
            "CiscoMailAlias"     = "dcloud-devops@cisco.com"
            "DataClassification" = "Cisco Confidential"
            "DataTaxonomy"       = "Cisco Operations Data"
            "Environment"        = "dev"
            "ResourceOwner"      = "dCloud"
            "Terraform"          = "true"
        }
        writer                                = false

        timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 3 to change, 2 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions in workspace "dev"?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.enable_replication: Creating...
aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical: Creating...
aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.enable_replication: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.enable_replication: Creation complete after 12s [id=aurora-pg13-cluster-repl]
module.psqldb.aws_rds_cluster.this[0]: Modifying... [id=psqldb]
aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
aws_db_parameter_group.enable_pglogical: Creation complete after 23s [id=aurora-pg13-pglogical]

Error: Failed to modify RDS Cluster (psqldb): InvalidParameterCombination: Cannot upgrade aurora-postgresql from 12.11 to 13.6
    status code: 400, request id: c9ee2dd1-e8de-44d9-9757-671ecb969c89

  on .terraform/modules/psqldb/main.tf line 47, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "this":
  47: resource "aws_rds_cluster" "this" {
```

Answer (score 3):

This major version upgrade is not possible according to the AWS docs.

Valid major target upgrade versions for `12.11` are `14.3` and `13.7`.
You will need to pick version `13.7` for a successful upgrade to major version 13.

You can read the docs for further information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.PostgreSQL.MajorVersion